# Copy files from Openshift to external unix machine

Tags: unix, openshift, sftp, rsync

I'm using rsync(oc client) to copy files from openshift pod to external unix machine on daily basis for batch activity. This process should be automated using shell script from external unix machine. Just a day old experience in open shift

```
oc login -u=<user> -p=<password> -n=<project>

oc rsync <pod-name>:/remote/dir/filename /unix/dir
```

Query 1:

But i need password less login or i should use encrypted password. So that password is not exposed. Any ways to accomplish this?

Query 2:

rsync is right approach? how about sftp file transfer? Not sure, how to use sftp to transfer files from openshift pod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Query 1, this is *absolutely* the perfect use case for [Service Accounts](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/authentication/understanding-and-creating-service-accounts.html). Once you create your Service Account, you would use `oc sa get-token <sa-name>` to get a *long lived* authentication token for the Service Account (note, you would need to still give your Service Account *authorization* to perform the `rsync`, `oc create rolebinding <sa-name> --clusterrole=edit`).

For Query 2, I believe that `rsync` would be the right approach. The other alternative is, instead of *pulling* your content from the pod, you could set something up that *pushes* your content from the pod into your unix machine. Obviously this would require the unix machine to be publicly available, so if that's a deal breaker, just still with `rsync`.

Comment: Thanks!.I have user account instead of service account to connect Pod from external linux machine. How can i access the token? I mean, i want to login inside pod without using password in shell script.

Comment: You should be _creating_ a Service Account. User tokens are short lived, Service Account tokens are long lived. You can create a Service Account within your own project.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do i need to hardcode the token within my shell script to access the pod? Eg: oc login <server> --token=<some token>. Any other way without hardcoding?

Comment: There's no way to avoid hardcoding the token _somewhere_ (it doesn't _have_ to be in your script). You could rely on environment variables, or possibly an external password service like Vault. Additionally, I _believe_ that once you `oc login` _once_ on the machine, you shouldn't have to `oc login` every time. So it _may_ be sufficient to `oc login` manually with the token, and then not have to ever again...assuming no one else is using the machine to perform `oc login`s. You can also pass `--token` _directly_ to the `oc rsync` command, and skip the login step in case this is a multi-user.

Answer (score 0):

Store ssh key as secret in OpenShift: [SSH Key Authentication](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-secrets-ssh-key-authentication)

This could be mounted to FS and direct access to the target machine can be achieved during [rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127352/specify-identity-file-id-rsa-with-rsync).

1. With ssh access from the pod to target machine, you can periodically check for a file existence in a particular folder, say `<target_ip>:<target_folder_conf>/trigger_to_copy/do_copy`
2. If `do_copy` exists, start rsync
3. Once done with rsync, delete `do_copy` at target machine
4. In the next run when pod checks for `do_copy`, it might not be present and rsync would happen next time when the file is created at the target machine
5. At remote machine, you can configure to create `do_copy` at required interval

Comment: Thanks! But i need to do other way around. Need to connect pod from external(target linux system) and pull file from pod.